# Passing each row of a mysql query to a php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i am running a mysql query to return all rows from a temp database, i then need to ammend some of the attributes in those rows so i am trying to return each row to an array so i can then reference the array and amend specific attributes of each row

im just stuck on how to get each row into its own array, im guessing i will need to use a 2d array for this however cannot figure out how to populate it from the mysql query into the 2d array. Im guessing it is something like i have tried below?

```
    $result_array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
 $result_array[] = $var;
foreach($row as $key => $var) {
// Insert into array
echo $var;
}
```

however when trying this i am getting a notice saying:

> Notice: Array to string conversion

any help pointing me in the right direction for this would be great

Comment: `$result_array[] = $var` doesn't make much sense, because `$var` isn't defined until you've run that inner foreach() loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking for, you literally want each row from the SQL query to be a single index in the `$result_array` array?

If that's the case, you're already getting it with `$row` - you can add that directly to the array:

```
$result_array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
    $result_array[] = $row;
}
```

You can modify the values inside the array either when you're adding them to the global array, or after:

```
foreach ($result_array as $index => $row) {
    $result_array[$index]['some_key'] = $row['some_key'] . ' [modified]';
}
```

*Side-note* (not answer specific)
I would recommend against using the old, deprecated `mysql_` functions and instead favor [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Both of these are easy to use, more secure than the older methods and offer a large range of features such as prepared statements.

The above can be written with mysqli like:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
    $results = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $results = $row;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```